# Equal Less and Greater List python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, compare

Hi guys I'm trying to figure out how to compare the previous number with the current one until the last digit.

this is the list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I need on each sequence of iteration the highest number (e.g. in the first one it's 10).
After the sequence is finalized it again begins counting from the beginning (1,2,3,4..etc) until a condition is reached.

Now the problem is that I get the result correctly all until the very last iteration, the max number should be in the 7 (as you can see: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

but the algorithm skips it. I tried with zip function even with iter loop the same issue.

example codes that yield the same results are the following:

```
def printElements(arr, n): 
      
    # Traverse array from index 1 to n-2 
    # and check for the given condition 
    for i in range(1, n - 1, 1): 
        if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1] and 
            arr[i] > arr[i + 1]): 
            print(arr[i], end = " ") 
  
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    n = len(arr) 
  
    printElements(arr, n) 


print(count_shelf)
```

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for prev, current in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
    print(prev,current)
    if prev > current:
        x = prev
        print(prev,'prev greater')
        print(current,'current')
```

results of the last alg:

```
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 1
10 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 1
6 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 1
7 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 1
3 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 1
5 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
4 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 1
8 prev greater
1 current
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7 ``
```

Comment: The last element is going to be an edge case because there's nothing after it that you can compare to.

Comment: can you be more precise please with the solution?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your algorithm needs. Do you want it to print "prev greater" or something if the last element is greater than the element before? If so, just add an extra if statement at the end of your for loop to do that.

Comment: on each iteration it should check whether the current number is greater than the previous. The thing is that the last number (7) is greater than the previous (6) and if i add that condition in that way (if prev < current) it obviously messes up the whole outcome since the condition is met more often than supposed to.

Comment: Well that's why you need to make a special if statement to take care of the edge case.

Comment: what do you consider as being specialif statement. Even by e.g. using[0::-1] or [-1] as for the last number to compate with the previous it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr.append(float('-inf'))
```

```
def printElements(arr, n): 
      
    # Traverse array from index 1 to n-2 
    # and check for the given condition 
    for i in range(1, n - 1, 1): 
        if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1] and 
            arr[i] > arr[i + 1]): 
            print(arr[i], end = " ") 
  
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    arr.append(float('-inf'))
    n = len(arr) 
  
    printElements(arr, n)
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work, but to be perfectly honest, this code is bugging me. Is there any more intuitive way of tackling this problem? Like with the zip function

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get the maximum value for each sequence.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

maxvals = [lst[x] for x in range(len(lst)) if x == len(lst)-1 or lst[x] > lst[x+1]]

print(maxvals)
```

Output

```
[10, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 8, 7]
```

I don't see any way to use `zip` to find the solution.